# c++ generic pointer to (member?) function

Tags: c++, function-pointers, boost-bind, pointer-to-member

I can't seem to declare a generic pointer to function.

Having these 2 functions to be called:

```
void myfunc1(std::string str)
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
struct X
{
        void f(std::string str){ std::cout<< str << std::endl;}
};
```

and these two function callers:

```
typedef void (*userhandler_t) (std::string);
struct example
{   
    userhandler_t userhandler_;

    example(userhandler_t userhandler): userhandler_(userhandler){}

    void call(std::string str)
    {   
        userhandler_(str);
    }
};
template<typename func_t>
void justfunc(func_t func)
{
    func("hello, works!");
}
```

when I try to use them with boost::bind to call the member function they give me compile errors.

this works:

```
example e1(&myfunc1);
e1.call("hello, world!");
justfunc(&myfunc1);
```

this doesn't:

```
X x;
example e2(boost::bind(&X::f, &x, _1));
e2.call("hello, world2!");
justfunc(boost::bind(&X::f, &x, _1));
```

How is this supposed to be done?

Comment: Neither the return type nor the argument type of `X::f` matches what `example` requires. What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`boost::bind` creates objects that behave like functions, not actual function pointers. Use the Boost.Function library to hold the result of calling `boost::bind`:

```
struct example
{
    boost::function<void(std::string)> userhandler_;
    ...
};
```

Comment: As Marcelo said, `boost::bind` creates __function objects__ (aka _functors_), not _function pointers_. +1 from me.

Comment: Thx, I missed that in the docs (was here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_boost_function)